# Calculate maximum units to buy with a max amount of money

Tags: javascript, math

I'm writing an agent to automate a procurement process:

```js
let perunitcost = 100;
let agentMaxQty = 60
let agentMaxTotal = 5000
let qtyToBePurchased = 0
```

This means the agent can buy products with a maximum total of 5000$ but can only procure up to 50 items; So, in this case, the agent will buy 50 units for a price of 100 (Total 5000).

I can do this via adding a for loop and brute force. But are their any optimize ways to do this without looping through all possibilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide the total funds available by the per unit cost, floor it to get the maximum units buyable, and take the minimum of *that* against the `agentMaxQty`:

```js
const perunitcost = 100;
const agentMaxQty = 60
const agentMaxTotal = 5000
const qtyToBePurchased = Math.min(
  Math.floor(agentMaxTotal / perunitcost),
  agentMaxQty
);
console.log(qtyToBePurchased);
```